# The element 'class' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'property'

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hbm

The hbm file is:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="EMSApplication.Domain.Employee, EMSApplication.Domain" table="ems_Employees" proxy="EMSApplication.Domain.IEmployee, EMSApplication.Domain">
    <property name="Username">
        <column name="Username" length="40" sql-type="nvarchar" not-null="true" index="Username"/>
    </property>
    <property name="Firstname">
        <column name="Firstname" length="40" sql-type="nvarchar" not-null="true" index="Firstname"/>
    </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Employee.cs:

```
namespace EMSApplication.Domain {
    public class Employee : IEmployee {
    private string username;
    private string firstname;

    public virtual string Firstname {
        get {
        return firstname;
        }
        set {
        firstname = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual string Username {
        get {
        return username;
        }
        set {
        username = value;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

And this is the IEmployee.cs:

```
namespace EMSApplication.Domain {
    interface IEmployee {
    string Firstname { get; set; }
    string Username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I am getting the exception:

> The element 'class' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has
>   invalid child element 'property' in namespace
>   'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of possible elements expected:
>   'meta, subselect, cache, synchronize, comment, tuplizer, id,
>   composite-id' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

I am using Spring.Net with NHibernate. The invocation of the hbm file is:

```
<object id="NHibernateSessionFactory" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject, Spring.Data.NHibernate32">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="MappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>assembly://EMSApplication/EMSApplication.Domain/EMSApplication.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    <property name="HibernateProperties">
    <dictionary>
        <entry key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
        <entry key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect"/>
        <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
        <entry key="proxyfactory.factory_class" value="NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate"/>
        <entry key="show_sql" value="true"/>
        <entry key="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <entry key="cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    </dictionary>
    </property>

    <property name="ExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="true" />
</object>
```

The project structure is:

[image]

Any help will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I am curious, what is your motive behind creating IEmployee?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing the `id` element, which comes before all properties in the schema.

Comment: Sure enough, was missing the ID element and property in my class. Ty!